# React onKeyUp Inconsistently Logs Case with Quick Shift+Key Presses

Tags: reactjs

I'm encountering a weird issue in a React application related to handling keyboard events. Specifically, when quickly pressing the Shift key followed by a letter key, the `onKeyUp` event handler logs the `e.key` value as lowercase. However, if I hold down the Shift key and then press a letter key, it correctly logs the uppercase character.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import "./styles.css";

function Input({ keyupHandler }) {
  return <input onKeyUp={keyupHandler} placeholder="Type here" />;
}

export default function App() {
  function keyupHandler(e) {
    console.log(e.key); // Logs lowercase for quick Shift+Key presses
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input keyupHandler={keyupHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've also created a [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/great-smoke-vkzsy2?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A10%2C4) to illustrate this behavior. The issue is specifically noticeable when the Shift key is quickly tapped followed by a letter key, resulting in e.key being logged as lowercase. If the Shift key is held down before pressing the letter key, the character is logged in the correct uppercase form.

I'm trying to understand why this timing difference affects the logged key case and how to ensure e.key correctly reflects the case of the key press, even for quick Shift+Key combinations.

Any insights into this behavior or suggestions for handling it effectively in React would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onKeyUp` event fires when the [key is released](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp). The fact that you see a lowercase in the event handler indicates that at the time you ***released*** the key you no longer had the shift key pressed.

The fact that you see a capital letter appear in the input is a separate behavior. This is based on the key (or combination of keys) that were pressed which can be determined by the `onKeyDown` handler. So even though it feels like you released the shift key before pressing the next character, the shift key's `onkeyup` event did not fire before the character's `onkeydown` event so that leads to a capital letter.

To confirm this, you can change your event handler to `onKeyDown` and see that a capital letter is logged always matching what the input displays